# How to rotate the arrow and direct it between two objects in a flowchart

Tags: tex-core, tikz-pgf

How can I output the arrow from the process "proc3" between the blocks "proc1" and "dec1"
I tried `\sbRelieryx` but it doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,circuits}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, text width=3cm, minimum   height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
        io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right 
        angle=110, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
        process/.style={rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
        decision/.style={diamond, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,draw=black},
        arrow/.style={thick,-stealth}}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
            \node (start) [startstop] {Begin};
            \node (proc1) [process, below = of start] {result = $a1$};
            \node (dec1) [decision, below = of proc1] {i < N - 1};
            \node (proc2) [process, below = of dec1] {result += d};
            \node (proc3) [process, below = of proc2] {i++};
            \node (proc4) [process, right of = dec1, xshift=5cm] {return result};
                    %%%%%LINES%%%%%
            \draw [arrow] (start) -- (proc1);
            \draw [arrow] (proc1) -- (dec1);
            \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (proc2) node[midway,left] {Yes};
            \draw [arrow] (proc2) -- (proc3);
            %\sbRelieryx {proc3} {proc1-dec1}
            \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (proc4) node[midway,above] {No};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output: [image: actual output]

what should happen: [image: desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `calc` library to calculate coordinates between nodes. For example `$(proc1.south)!0.5!(dec1.north)$` will give you the coordinate halfway between the two coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,circuits,calc}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, text width=3cm, minimum   height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
        io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right 
        angle=110, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
        process/.style={rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
        decision/.style={diamond, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,draw=black},
        arrow/.style={thick,-stealth}}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
            \node (start) [startstop] {Begin};
            \node (proc1) [process, below = of start] {result = $a1$};
            \node (dec1) [decision, below = of proc1] {i < N - 1};
            \node (proc2) [process, below = of dec1] {result += d};
            \node (proc3) [process, below = of proc2] {i++};
            \node (proc4) [process, right of = dec1, xshift=5cm] {return result};
                    %%%%%LINES%%%%%
            \draw [arrow] (start) -- (proc1);
            \draw [arrow] (proc1) -- (dec1);
            \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (proc2) node[midway,left] {Yes};
            \draw [arrow] (proc2) -- (proc3);
            \draw [arrow] (proc3) -- ++(-3,0) |- ($(proc1.south)!0.5!(dec1.north)$);
            \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (proc4) node[midway,above] {No};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: n1ce! ur the best

Comment: @avebass You're welcome!

Comment: hi, how to convert this flowchart (tikz) to .svg so that you can edit it in Adobe Illustrator for example

Comment: @avebass if you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: answer please the new question

Comment: @avebass You shouldn't just dump an image on people. Add a [mre] to your question of what you already have, so people don't have to start from scratch.